# Display Meta data from a JetEngine Checkbox Field - Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor, jet-engine

I have a Checkbox Field with the Post Meta field name "select-languages".

I am trying to show the Meta Data from it in an Elementor Template, by retrieving it via a "Dynamic Field" elementor widget, but I'm getting "Array" as output.

I've tried the "Filter field output" and selected as a Callback "Checkbox Field Value".

Is there another way I could display the values selected in the checkbox with a delimter, say ",", using Elementor?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else stumbbles uppon the same issue, I figured out the problem was the way I was saving the custom field labels.

There is an option in **JetEngine Custom post type** -> **Meta Fields** -> **Save as array**.
**This is the descriptor:** If this option is enabled checked values will be stored as plain PHP array. Use this option if this meta value will be edited from front-end form

Enabling this displayed my field as a list, sepparated by ",", just like I wanted.